# Is it possible for the Contact page to have 2 URL aliases? or clone it?

Tags: routes, uri

My client is wants the Contact page to be available in more than one place in the menu system. Problem is this would interfere with how sidebar menus load. so ideally it would be nice to have 2 URL aliases for it,  …or as alternative just clone the page.

Does anyone know how to do either of these options. I need to do the same for the User page.

big thanks in advance!

Comment: My recommendation would be to add an URL redirect from a 'fake' alias to the real page. It's not good to have duplicated alias/pages as it might affect SEO.

Answer (score 0):

The [Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) would allow you to create another url for for your contact page. One would simply redirect to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many aliases as you like that points to one page (which, in this case, is Contact)

Comment: i have to have 2 diff URL's like this